# Comprehensive biology or anatomy wordbank

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology

I teach A&P for bio non majors. I have a special needs student whose accommodation requires a word bank for any anatomy identification questions I have on the exam. I would like to present the student with a 'master wordbank' (presumably hundreds of words in length) that would act as a word bank for all the exams in the course. I'm surprised to be unable to find much of anything online. Has anyone seen something like this?

Comment: The index of your textbook?

Comment: I agree that your textbook's index or glossary is probably your best bet. Because anatomy can be taught at so many different levels (breadth and depth) and you're teaching at a fairly basic level, you'd have a hard time finding  a list elsewhere that emphasizes/includes what you want but doesn't weigh you down with terms your class does not cover

Comment: this textbook has no such thing unfortunately

Comment: I've been trying to find something similiar so far all I have found is an academic headword  list. https://www.victoria.ac.nz/lals/resources/academicwordlist/awl-headwords/Headwords-of-the-Academic-Word-List.pdf

Answer (score 1):

So I found a good list. Behold: wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_biology

Comment: If you are teaching A&P, then this list will definitely not have all possible terms. For example, there are no named muscles in this list (or at least the first 5 most obvious I searched for were not), which normally would be included in an A&P exam.

Comment: @kmm this is not A&P at harvard medical college. However, that's not good regarding the muscles. When i did some random testing I didn't cross check any of those.. do you remember a muscle you queried?

Comment: Look for "rectus", "biceps" and "femur". None is on that list.

Comment: @kmm To be fair they are not really headwords but specific terms for an individual object. If you want to include ALL of those you would be better off with the entire biological dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at some biological terminologies or ontologies. These can be browsed online using portals like the [OLS](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/) or [Bioportal](http://bioportal.bioontology.org). You can restrict your search to particular domains or sources, such as the FMA for adult human anatomy and [Uberon](http://obofoundry.org/ontology/uberon.html) for general metazoan and comparative anatomy. This may be overkill for your purposes, as these ontologies are intended for computational applications rather than as an educational reference source. For example, terms are linked to other terms via different relationship types. However, this extra information may turn out to be useful, and the developers of these ontologies may be interested in helping with educational use cases (I am the developer of Uberon and this is something I am interested in).

If you wanted to extract a table of terms from one of these, perhaps restricted to a domain (e.g. human muscles) then this may be possible with a bit of work with some of the online interfaces, or it's something that could be done by someone with programmatic skills. Someone on bioinformatics.stackechange.com could help with that task. Many of these are available via open and unrestrictive licenses so there should be no legal issue here.